# Should I destroy File object after File.read and File.open in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

Suppose two kinds of ruby File operations.

Firstly,

```
file = File.open("xxx")
file.close
```

Secondly,

```
file = File.read("xxx")
file.close
```

It's known to all that we should close file after we finish using it. But, in the second block of code, Ruby interpreter throw an error message shown below:

```
in `<main>': undefined method `close' for #<String:0x000000022a3a08> (NoMethodError)
```

I need not to use `file.close` in the second case? I wonder why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `File.read` method returns string with content of the file, not the `File` object. And yes, you don't need to use `close` explicitly if you use `File.read` method, because ruby does it for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

[Marek Lipka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811921/2767755) answered correctly, I just wanted you to point to the documentation sentences again.

> I need not to use file.close in the second case?

You don't need to do so.

Read the doc [`IO::read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-read) carefully :

> Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, then returns length bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file). `read` ***ensures the file is closed before returning.***